# Как определить находится ли одна точка с координатами в радиусе другой google maps

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api, google-maps, react-native, expo

у меня есть координаты своей локации и координаты ближайших кафе и баров на гугл мапс, нужно определить нахожусь ли я ближе чем на 100 метров к ним, если да - идет один вариант кода, если нет - другой, как получить дистанцию между двумя точками на гугл мапс?

Comment: https://github.com/Turfjs/turf-distance

Answer (score 0):

нашел ответ здесь, если кому пригодится

https://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5260423/torad-javascript-function-throwing-error

Comment: добро пожаловать на stack overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)